# Can we bring a stroller on DC Metrorail?

Tags: usa, public-transport, children, washington-dc

We're planning a trip to bring my 2.5 year old son to visit the National Museum of Natural History and the National Zoo in the US.

Our hotel is right by the metrorail, and our plan is to take it in to the museums, returning for nap time and the evening.

We're traveling mid-week (Thursday and Friday), and want to get in to the museum/zoo as early as possible.

Is it permitted to bring a stroller?  Will this be practical if we run into heavy commuter traffic, or should we schedule to avoid the worst of the rush (and if so, what is the best time in the morning to travel?)?

Comment: As a side tip, exit at Cleveland Park for the National Zoo, then return from Woodley Park-Zoo/Adams-Morgan. Despite Woodley Park's name-grabbing, they are about equidistant from the entrance (0.4mi/650m or so)-- but from Cleveland Park it is a downhill walk.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't see any reason why you wouldn't be able to.  Links w.r.t the subject:

- [Rules and Manners](http://www.wmata.com/rail/railrules.cfm)
- [Blog in Washington Post](http://www.washingtonpost.com/blogs/on-parenting/post/navigating-metro-with-a-stroller/2011/09/10/gIQAfoxjSK_blog.html)
- [Similar question on Yelp](http://www.yelp.com/topic/washington-strollers-on-the-metro)

Generally speaking strollers during rush hour are annoying because they take up too much space and one has to be careful around them so not to hurt your child but noone will say anything to you if you bring it on.

Comment: I would, however, avoid traveling (with or without stroller) with small children during Metro's "peak of the peak" hours, around 8am-9am and 5pm-6pm weekdays. It will be so crowded in the core that you may find it difficult to board at some stations; I can speak from morning experiences at Woodley Park on the Red Line and Court House on the Orange Line.

Comment: Guess this is one way of getting a USA badge :)

Comment: @Berwyn Wasn't the intent but I am fine with the benefit.